# Unable to compile less for bootstrap-material-design

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs, less, bootstrap-material-design

I have a clean install of https://github.com/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design. I tried to compile it using `grunt` but I get the following error:

```
 Running "less:material" (less) task  FileError:
 '../bower_components/bootstrap/less/variables.less' wasn't found.
 Tried -
 bower_components/bootstrap/less/variables.less,bower_components/bootstrap/less/variables.less,../bower_components/bootstrap/less/variables.less
 in less/_import-bs-less.less on line 1, column 1:  1 @import
 "../bower_components/bootstrap/less/variables.less";  2 //@import
 "../bower_components/bootstrap/less/mixins.less";
```

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 4):

You're getting the error because the grunt less plugin is not able to find a file that needs to be imported. Since the file is pointing to `/bower_components` directory, the issue is probably that you forgot to run `bower install` which creates `/bower_components` directory and installs the missing files.